# bash history expansion (with word selection) mishandles the |& sequence

Tags: bash, io-redirection, bash4, command-history

Bash has two features that both work, but not together.

1. **|&** is an alternate syntax for piping both stdout and stderr. Example: 
   `cmd |& tee file`  is equivalent to 
   `cmd 2>&1 | tee file`
2. **!** history expressions allows word selection such as `!*` for all but word 0 (and it can also be written `!:*`). Example:

```
   echo one two 
   echo zero !*
```

The second echo produces
`echo zero one two`

So far, so good. But when combined, bash does the wrong thing.

```
echo one |& tee /tmp/file
one
echo zero !*
echo zero one | & tee /tmp/file
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

(The line "one" and the line starting with "bash:" are output and the line
echo zero one | & tee /tmp/file
is history reiterating the expansion it generated and appears because I have the `histexpand` option (same as `set -H`) enabled.)

Note that the history expansion inserted a space between **|** and **&**. That's not helpful, and in my opinion, it is not correct. I wanted the `|&` digraph left together, so the expansion should have been
`echo zero one |& tee /tmp/file`
(History expansion doesn't alter the `|&` sequence unless history word selection is used.)

Is this a known bash bug? Is there a workaround, other than

1. Using the 2>&1 syntax when piping or
2. Editing the history expansion before execution?

Is there a bash version with a fix for this?
How/where should I submit this bug?

(I mostly use GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) on Alma 8.9.)

Comment: Yes it's a known problem that history expansion does not recognize the same tokens as the main parser. The appropriate forum to discuss this is the bug-bash@gnu.org mailing list (hosted on lists.gnu.org). There's also an IRC channel `#bash` on the Libera network where many developers loiter, though as far as I know the principal maintainer Chet Ramey does not have any social media presence other than the mailing list.

Comment: Many people - including those who contribute to improving Bash itself - never use the `!` history expansion, and as a result bugs and issues in the history mechanism receive little attention. Many people claim that it's quicker to simply use `^R` to search the history and then edit it. However I've found it invaluable to be able to combine components from multiple history lines, such as `vimdiff <( !-2 ) <( !! )`

Comment: They excel in different ways. `!!:gs/from/to/` is significantly easier than making the same change in multiple places on a prior command line.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's a well known problem that the main parser and the history expansion mechanism don't agree on what constitutes a token.

You can use the `bashbug` utility that's part of the Bash suite to submit a bug report, but since it's already known, I suggest joining the `bug-bash@gnu.org` mailing list for further discussion & feedback.

In the meantime I strongly recommend `shopt -s histverify histreedit` to make sure that the expansion generated by `!` is what you intend before trying to run them, and to allow re-editing if the expansion fails.

Personally I avoid the `|&` except for quick hacks, because of its very weird split personality.

One might reasonably expect that any "pipe operator" would be set up before the redirections in the components on either side of it, but in the case of the `|&` operator, it first sets up stdout of the left side, then does all the internal redirections on the left side and *only then* does it do the equivalent of `2>&1`.

So if you write:

```
{ foo >&3 |& bar ; } 3>> /some/file
```

then both stdout and stderr from `foo` winds up in `/some/file`, and stdin for `bar` is empty.

If anyone thinks this is "obvious" or "preferred", please feel free to leave a comment, but I think it's pretty insane.

Comment: To join the `bug-bash@gnu.org` mailing list, follow the usual mailing convention: send a message with the subject `subscribe` to its control address `bug-bash-request@gnu.org`, which is the list address with `-request` inserted just before the `@`.

Comment: Late redirection of stderr with |& is at least well documented. History expansion on the other hand is documented very poorly, which I suspect is the main reason why most users are reluctant to use it.

Comment: You're right that it's documented, but most novices are reticent to read the manual, preferred to extrapolate from examples they've been given. Both sections are about as well documented, but `&>` is naturally much shorter and so easier to grasp. And I agree that the fact that "history words" and "shell words" are not (quite) the same needs to be hammered home much more forcefully.